# datatable json data add new row not working

Tags: jquery, json, datatable

jQuery:

```
var data = JSON.parse(response);
$.each(data, function(i) {
    console.log(data[i].Serial);
    table.row.add([{
        ".Serial": data[i].Serial,
        ".Purchase_id": data[i].Purchase_id,
        ".Item": data[i].Item,
        ".HSN": data[i].HSN,
        ".Unit": data[i].Unit,
        ".Quantity": data[i].Quantity,
        ".Purchase_rate": data[i].Purchase_rate,
        ".Discount": data[i].Discount,
        ".Discount_2": data[i].Discount_2,
        ".Net_rate": data[i].Net_rate,
        ".CGST_Percentage": data[i].CGST_Percentage,
        ".SGST_Percentage": data[i].SGST_Percentage,
        ".IGST_Percentage": data[i].IGST_Percentage,
        ".Rate_after_tax": data[i].Rate_after_tax,
        ".CGST": data[i].CGST,
        ".SGST": data[i].SGST,
        ".IGST": data[i].IGST,
        ".Net_amount_without_tax": data[i].Net_amount_without_tax,
        ".Net_amount": data[i].Net_amount,
        ".ID": data[i].ID
    }]).draw();
});
```

Response data:

```
[  
   {  
      "ID":"35",
      "Serial":"1",
      "Purchase_id":"10",
      "Item":"famous sticker",
      "Unit":"Piece",
      "HSN":"84022020",
      "Quantity":"10000",
      "Purchase_rate":"40",
      "Discount":"0",
      "Discount_2":"0",
      "Net_rate":"40",
      "CGST_Percentage":"0",
      "SGST_Percentage":"0",
      "IGST_Percentage":"12",
      "Rate_after_tax":"44.8",
      "CGST":"0",
      "SGST":"0",
      "IGST":"48000",
      "Net_amount_without_tax":"400000",
      "Net_amount":"448000",
      "Item_id":"27"
   },
   {  
      "ID":"36",
      "Serial":"1",
      "Purchase_id":"11",
      "Item":"famous sticker",
      "Unit":"Piece",
      "HSN":"84022020",
      "Quantity":"1",
      "Purchase_rate":"10",
      "Discount":"10",
      "Discount_2":"0",
      "Net_rate":"9",
      "CGST_Percentage":"6",
      "SGST_Percentage":"6",
      "IGST_Percentage":"0",
      "Rate_after_tax":"10.08",
      "CGST":"0.54",
      "SGST":"0.54",
      "IGST":"0",
      "Net_amount_without_tax":"9",
      "Net_amount":"10.08",
      "Item_id":"27"
   }
]
```

HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="Serial"></td>
        <td class="Purchase_id"></td>
        <td class="Item"></td>
        <td class="HSN"></td>
        <td class="Unit"></td>
        <td class="Quantity"></td>
        <td class="Purchase_rate"></td>
        <td class="Discount"></td>
        <td class="Discount_2"></td>
        <td class="Net_rate"></td>
        <td class="CGST_Percentage"></td>
        <td class="SGST_Percentage"></td>
        <td class="IGST_Percentage"></td>
        <td class="Rate_after_tax"></td>
        <td class="CGST"></td>
        <td class="SGST"></td>
        <td class="IGST"></td>
        <td class="Net_amount_without_tax"></td>
        <td class="Net_amount"></td>
        <td class="ID"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Anyone can please tell me Why is it not setting up data to table? I want to set data respectively on td class but it not working. When I am displaying data in the console in data then it works but when I am adding data to table then it not working. How can I resolve this issue? Sorry for my weak English. please edit the question so this question can help others.

Answer (score 0):

try without the {  } that enclose the data also it should be easier to work with

```
$.each(data, function(i,item) {

table.row.add([
    ".Serial": item.Serial,
    ".Purchase_id": item.Purchase_id,
    ".Item": item.Item,
    ".HSN": item.HSN,
    ".Unit": item.Unit,
    ".Quantity": item.Quantity,
    ".Purchase_rate": item.Purchase_rate,
    ".Discount": item.Discount,
    ".Discount_2": item.Discount_2,
    ".Net_rate": item.Net_rate,
    ".CGST_Percentage": item.CGST_Percentage,
    ".SGST_Percentage": item.SGST_Percentage,
    ".IGST_Percentage": item.IGST_Percentage,
    ".Rate_after_tax": item.Rate_after_tax,
    ".CGST": item.CGST,
    ".SGST": item.SGST,
    ".IGST": item.IGST,
    ".Net_amount_without_tax": item.Net_amount_without_tax,
    ".Net_amount": item.Net_amount,
    ".ID": item.ID
]).draw();  });
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: well just dont copy paste

Answer (score 0):

Probably you'll consider using jquery append method to create the table like the following. It eliminates the need to give a class to each table data `td`

```js
var response = [  
   {  
      "ID":"35",
      "Serial":"1",
      "Purchase_id":"10",
      "Item":"famous sticker",
      "Unit":"Piece",
      "HSN":"84022020",
      "Quantity":"10000",
      "Purchase_rate":"40",
      "Discount":"0",
      "Discount_2":"0",
      "Net_rate":"40",
      "CGST_Percentage":"0",
      "SGST_Percentage":"0",
      "IGST_Percentage":"12",
      "Rate_after_tax":"44.8",
      "CGST":"0",
      "SGST":"0",
      "IGST":"48000",
      "Net_amount_without_tax":"400000",
      "Net_amount":"448000",
      "Item_id":"27"
   },
   {  
      "ID":"36",
      "Serial":"1",
      "Purchase_id":"11",
      "Item":"famous sticker",
      "Unit":"Piece",
      "HSN":"84022020",
      "Quantity":"1",
      "Purchase_rate":"10",
      "Discount":"10",
      "Discount_2":"0",
      "Net_rate":"9",
      "CGST_Percentage":"6",
      "SGST_Percentage":"6",
      "IGST_Percentage":"0",
      "Rate_after_tax":"10.08",
      "CGST":"0.54",
      "SGST":"0.54",
      "IGST":"0",
      "Net_amount_without_tax":"9",
      "Net_amount":"10.08",
      "Item_id":"27"
   }
]
;
var table = $("table tbody");
var data = response;
$.each(data, function(i) {
    console.log(data[i].Serial);
  var d = data[i];
  var tr = $("<tr></tr>");
  for(var e in d){
      tr.append("<td>"+d[e]+"</td>");
    }
  table.append(tr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tbody>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```